# Ask aspell to skip part of document

Tags: ubuntu, spell-checking, aspell

I'm using *aspell* to spell check LaTeX documents on Linux. Very often my documents contain samples of code in various programming languages, and I would like *aspell* to simply skip those lines while spell checking.

Is there anything I can write in my document to turn *aspell* off on a section of text? Something like:

```
This line should be spell checked.

% Hey, aspell, don't check the following lines
\begin{lstlisting}
if (xyzzy > foobar) {
    doSomethingSilly();
}
\end{lstlisting}
% Hey, aspell, please check the following

This line should be spell checked.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aspell to skip part of document

---

**spellcheck LaTeX documents**

LaTeX documents require a little more work.

command

```
aspell --lang=en_GB --add-tex-command="mySkip op" -c teste.tex
```

- put at start `\mySkip[` after **{** again a `\mySkip[`

teste.tex

```
\documentclass{article} 

\makeatletter
\def\myComment{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{Hello #1, have you met #2?}
\def\@without#1{Goodbye #1.}
\makeatother


\mySkip[
 if (xyzzy > foobar) {
\mySkip[
   doSomethingSilly();
   doSomethingOther();
   doSomethingExtra();
 }
]]
This liine should be spell checked.
```

Problem after every opening curly brace **{** in the code you need `\mySkip[`

```
\mySkip[
 if (abcdef > foobar) {
\mySkip[
   doSomethingSilly();
   if (test > 100) {
\mySkip[
     doSomethingOther();
   }
   doSomethingExtra();
 }
]]
This liine should be spell checked.
```

With a search and replace you can make the code ready
before replace

[image]

after replace

[image]

---

For `sgml` it's easier.

Step by step

- create a folder `aspell60-7`
- copy teste.html into.

teste.html

```
This line should be spell checked.

<nospell>
if (xyzzy > foobar) {
    doSomethingSilly();
}
</nospell>
<script>
if (xyzzy > foobar) {
    doSomethingSilly();
}
</script>

This line should be spell checked.
```

- change a letter in `teste.html`
- cd into folder `aspell60-7`

[image]

- enter following command

---

```
aspell --lang=en_GB --add-filter=sgml --add-sgml-skip=nospell --add-sgml-skip=script -c -S teste.html
```

after run the command

[image]

- after enter 1 for `1) line` .
- `aspell` terminates.
- Gedit tells file `teste.html` was changed.
- after `new load`
- previously modified word `liine` is correct.
- all lines surrounded by `<nospell>` and `<script>` are ignored.

[image]

this also works in windows, but only with `aspell6`.